# In context of Docker images, which Ubuntu image version fixes the CVE-2018-10000 issue with Glibc?

Tags: 17.10, security, docker, glibc

We are trying to address a security issue with Ubuntu 17.10 image (ubuntu:17.10) which uses glibc version 2.26. This has a security vulnerability CVE-2018-10000 that is related to integer overflow.

Inspite of googling around, I wasn't able to find the updated Ubuntu image that fixes this issue.

Issue Link: https://www.cvedetails.com/cve-details.php?t=1&cve_id=CVE-2018-10000

Comment: The presently up to date stable Ubuntu version 18.04 comes with glibc 2.27. Is the issue fixed there?

Comment: Your description of [CVE-2018-10000](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve-details.php?t=1&cve_id=CVE-2018-10000) does not see to match the [actual vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-10000).

Comment: @Takkat We would like to use 17.10 version of Ubuntu.  Is there a minor version of 17.10 with the fix?

Comment: @Sid: you probably will not want to continue using 17.10 in one weeks time. It will reach end of support by then.

Answer (score 1):

Each CVE is tracked as a Launchpad Bug with a predictable URL. Here's the Launchpad bug for that particular CVE:

https://launchpad.net/bugs/cve/CVE-2018-10000

This particular issue does not seem to affect any Ubuntu software, so no work is planned.

If you have further questions on Ubuntu Security, ask them here on AskUbuntu first. If you can show that the Ubuntu Security Team was *demonstrably* mistaken in an assessment, then contact them at #ubuntu-security or #ubuntu-hardened on Freenode IRC.